# How to run appium in ubuntu

Tags: android, selenium, appium

I have installed appium and appium doctor in my machine. After running the  command in my terminal. i don't know what to do next could anyone please tell me what to do after i run the command appium in my terminal

```
appium
```

[image]

Could any one can share appium tutorials for ionic1

Answer (score 0):

**Your Appium server is ready!**

Next steps are:

1. [Set path](https://medium.com/testcult/configuring-appium-in-ubuntu-from-scratch-a9f8edc02d13)
2. [Install IDE(IntelliJ IDEA or eclipse)](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/#section=linux)
3. [Write your case (including desired capabilities)](https://nishantverma.gitbooks.io/appium-for-android/writing_first_android_test/)
4. Run